# phantomjs terminated with signal SIGSEGV

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, segmentation-fault, mocha-phantomjs

When I run "mocha-phantomjs -R dot /test/file.html", The Program catch the error "phantomjs terminated with signal SIGSEGV". I don't know what happened! What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`upx -d phantomjs` can fix my problem. Phantomjs can run on my OS X 10.10.5.